# add dropdown list in google sheet by using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to add some names from array to list dropdown not work.

This is my code:

```
function dataDrpdwon() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var item = ss.addListItem();
    item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
    .setChoices([
    item.createChoice('Cats'),
    item.createChoice('Dogs')
]);

}
```

after add `=dataDrpdwon()` in any cell I see this error `TypeError: ss.addListItem is not a function (line 3).` any help to fix.

I want to add `=dataDrpdwon()` in any cell and see List dropdown.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to add a [dropdown item](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7322334?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdropdown) to a Form, or a [Sheets dropdown](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0):

addListItem is a function in ListItem Class.
Here documentation `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item`

Answer (score 0):

addListItem is not available for on the ActiveSpreadsheet object, I think it's only available for Forms.

I'm not overly familiar with App Script, but drop downs within Sheets/Excel are typically done via validation. So you may need a different approach. A quick search found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262553/create-dynamic-dropdown-list-in-the-google-apps-script) that might put you in the right direction.